# How to run script in Solaris after boot once

Tags: solaris

I looking for the right way to run shell script first boot Solaris.
I need to run resize command, there is a my script

```
#!/bin/sh -ux
echo "#!/bin/sh -ux" > /etc/rc3.d/S90scale
echo "/sbin/zpool set autoexpand=on rpool" >> /etc/rc3.d/S90scale
echo "/sbin/zpool online -e rpool c1d0" >> /etc/rc3.d/S90scale
echo "rm /etc/rc3.d/S90scale" >> /etc/rc3.d/S90scale
echo "/sbin/shutdown -y -i6 -g0" >> /etc/rc3.d/S90scale
chmod a+x /etc/rc3.d/S90scale
```

actually script working properly, but unfortunately resize do not work. When I do the same things from user session everything just fine.

What exactly I doing wrong?

Comment: When you run the script you're logged in and your .profile has been loaded which configures your environment. At boot your .profile hasn't been loaded, so the script is running in a different environment. Could be that at a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is not the "right" one to run a script once after boot as it uses the legacy approach. The correct way would be to create an [`smf` service that runs once](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21798/firstboot-1.html). However, it does work anyway with Solaris 10 and 11 as the `rc` scripts while deprecated are still processed so I won't elaborate more about `smf`.

The main issue is you don't check for errors and whatever happens, it remove the script and reboot preventing any analysis to occur.

I would suggest to modify your script to log what is happening in a file and quit on error:

```
#!/bin/ksh
cat > /etc/rc3.d/S90scale <<%EOF%
exec > /var/tmp/S90scale.log 2>&1 # logs everything to file
set -xe                           # show commands and exits on error
/sbin/zpool set autoexpand=on rpool
/sbin/zpool online -e rpool c1d0
mv /etc/rc3.d/S90scale  /etc/rc3.d/_S90scale
/sbin/shutdown -y -i6 -g0
%EOF%
chmod a+x /etc/rc3.d/S90scale
```

After the next reboot complete, you should have a look to the `/var/tmp/S90scale.log` file and possibly see an error message there.

Comment: Actually I had another error, not linked by script, but  logging way using exec is extremely useful, thank you